# ubercart file download setting problem

Tags: file, download, ubercart, setting

Hi I am using drupal 6.x and ubercart 2.x. I trie dto create a product,but when it comes to add the file download feature I am getting some issue. I put a folder called downloads in the drupal folder and one file inside the download folder.then I gave the path as "drupal/downloads but it is telling that drupal/downloads is not a valid file or directory"

I tied the following file paths too

1.www.mysite.com/drupal/downloads/faq.ods

2.drupal/downloads/faq.ods

3.drupal/faq.ods(after putting faq.ods in the drupal folder.

But still I am getting the same message. Plesae some body help me

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for a path rather than a URL. You should probably aim to find out from your hosting company what the absolute path for your webroot is (e.g. www.mysite.com may actually be on disk as `/users/mysite.com/httpdocs`) and put in that followed by `/drupal/downloads`